# Stabilizer of an element in a Group Action

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a set $A$.

1. If $b \in \mathcal{O}_a$ i.e ($b=g.a$) for some $g \in G$. Then
   $G_b=g.G_a.g^{-1}$.
2. Let $b,c \in \mathcal{O}_a$.  If $b\ne c$ then $G_b\ne G_c$

These means that for every element in the orbit, there exists a distinct conjugate of $G_a$. Which means that

(number of conjugates of $G_a$ in $G$) $\geq$ (number of elements in $\mathcal{O}_a$).

Now the LHS=$\frac{|G|}{|N(G_a)|}$ and RHS=$\frac{|G|}{|G_a|}$
$\implies$ $\frac{|G|}{|N(G_a)|} \geq  \frac{|G|}{|G_a|}$.

Now since $G$ is finite. Can we conclude that $|G_a| \geq |N(G_a)|$ ?

And since we already know that $|G_a| \leq |N(G_a)|$. We conclude that $N(G_a)=G_a$.

If this is true, then in **group actions** from any **finite abelian group** to any set will have trivial stabilizers.

Are these results actually correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 2. is not true. You may consider the action from $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ to an equilateral triangle $ABC$ given by rotations. You have only one orbit, and each vertex has trivial stabilizer.

For a counterexample for your last statement (and also for 2.), you may consider the action of $\mathbb Z$ to an equilateral triangle $ABC$ given by rotations. Then stabilizer of each vertex is $3\mathbb Z$. Even easier, you can take any group $G$ acting trivially (i.e. by formula $g\cdot x=x$) on any set $X$; all stabilizers are equal to $G$, so non-trivial.